Existence of solution of Cauchy problem in a neighbourhood of $\left(x_0, 0\right)$
We consider the Cauchy problem
$$x(u - x)u_x + u(u - y)u_y = 0,$$
$$u(x, 0) = 2x.$$
We have to study the existence of solution in a neighbourhood of each $\left(x_0, 0\right)$, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.
So, by the transversality condition of quasilinear PDE, I found that if $x_0 \neq 0$ then there exists solution in a neighbourhood of $\left(x_0, 0\right)$. However, if $x_0 = 0$, this condition doesn't tell us anything about the existence of solution. Is there a way to show the non-existence (or the existence) of solution in that case?

$$x(u - x)u_x + u(u - y)u_y = 0$$
The method of characteristics (Charpit-Lagrange) easily leads to the general solution on the form of implicit equation :
$$u^2-xy+(u-x)F(u)=0\tag 1$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
With condition $u(x,0)=2x$ the function $F$ is determined :
$$F(u)=2u$$
This leads to the particular solution satisfying both the PDE and the condition :
$$u^2-2xu+xy=0$$
$$u(x,y)=x\pm\sqrt{x(x-y)}$$
Considering the real solutions only :
$$\begin{cases}
u(x,y)=x+\sqrt{x(x-y)}\quad\text{on}\quad x>0\quad\text{and}\quad y<x \\
u(x,y)=x-\sqrt{x(x-y)}\quad\text{on}\quad x<0\quad\text{and}\quad y>x\\
u(x,y)=0\quad\text{on}\quad x=0
\end{cases}$$
On $y=x$ the solution of the PDE is $u(x,y)=x$ but doesn't satisfies the condition except at $(0,0)$.

